# Rearrange/order bars in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to order the bars as "0", "5", "10", "20". The basic ggplot() keeps placing the bars out of order. Here is my code:

```
data <- data.frame(
  Treatment=c("0","5", "10","20") ,  
  Salinity=c(21.8,22.5, 22.5, 23.5))

ggplot(data, aes(Treatment, Salinity, fill = x)) +   
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  ylim(0,25)+
  ggtitle("Salicornia pacifica" )
```

And output
Places the bars as "0", "10", "20", "5"

How do I set the order I want the bars, or rearrange the bars?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlZas.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can order the data columns into an arbitrary order using `factors` like this:

```
data1 <- data                                                 # Replicate original data
data1$x <- factor(data1$x,                                    # Change ordering manually
                  levels = c("0", "5", "10", "20"))

ggplot(data1, aes(x, y)) +                                    # Manually ordered barchart
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your `Treatment` column is a character. Hence, ggplot2 will by default order the categories in alphabetical order . And alphabetically any string starting with a "2", e.g. "20" comes before a string starting with a "5".

To prevent that you have to convert to a factor with the levels set in your desired order, which in your case could be achieved by first converting to a `numeric` and afterwards to a `factor`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data, aes(factor(as.numeric(Treatment)), Salinity)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  ylim(0, 25) +
  ggtitle("Salicornia pacifica")
```

[image]